# Match consecutive terms in row with ignoring spaces

Tags: regex

can you tell me how to write regex which match consecutive terms with some pattern with ignoring whitespaces between them?

For instance I have string like this: `%{aaa}    %{vvv} hello %{aaa} %{aaa}`

and I want match this: **%{aaa} %{vvv}** and **%{aaa} %{aaa}** where pattern for terms should like this:

`%{<anything>}`

I have no idea idea how to write regex for this, but it's very important to me. Thank you in advice.

Comment: @cfillion I'm sorry I press wrong key .. it's just %

Comment: This should work: `%\{[^}]*}(?:\s*%\{[^}]*})*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match multiple tagged blocks separated by whitespaces, you may use this regex:

```
%\{[^}]*}(?:\s*%\{[^}]*})*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8cS3lT/1)

**Details:**

- `%\{[^}]*}`: Match a single block starting with `%{` and ending with `}`
- `(?:\s*%\{[^}]*})*`: Match 0 or more of such tags separated by 0 or more whitespaces

Comment: thank you, is possible to match just 2 and more terms in row?

Comment: Yes that is easy. Just change last `*` with `+` to make it `%\{[^}]*}(?:\s*%\{[^}]*})+`